# How to refresh my server control after INSERT in ajax manner?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

How to refresh my server control after INSERT in ajax manner .

**My .aspx :**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ListView ID="lv_familyrelation" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="RelationContainer" ItemType="DomainClasses.FAMILYRELATION">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <fieldset id="FieldSet1">

                        <legend>Relations</legend>
                        <br />
                        <a id="lbtnInitInsert" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr" onclick="EditForInsert(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>

                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    Code
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    Insert
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RelationContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </fieldset>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 code">
                                <%#:Item.RELATION_CODE%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 name">
                                <%#:Item.RELATION_NAME%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <a id="lbtn_edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr" onclick="Edit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <div id="insertForm" class="container-fluid editForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    Add
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a onclick="CloseInsertDialog(); return false;" style="cursor: pointer;">Close</a>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    Code
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    Name
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12 code_ins">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_relation_code_ins" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 name_ins">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_relation_name_ins" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn_close" value="Close" onclick="CloseInsertDialog(); return false;" />

                    <input type="submit" id="btn_insert" value="Add" onclick="Insert(); return false;" />

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

---

**Script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var row;
        var id, name;

        function Edit(editButton) {


            row = $(editButton).parent().parent();
            id = $('.code', row).text().trim();
            name = $('.name', row).text().trim();


            row.addClass("highlightRow");
            DisplayEditDialog();
            return false;
        }

        function DisplayEditDialog() {
            $("#lbl_relation_code").text(id);
            $("#txt_relation_name").val(name);
            $("#editForm").show();
        }

        function EditForInsert(editButton) {

            $("#insertForm").show();

            return false;
        }

        function Insert(e) {

            name = $("#txt_relation_name_ins").val();
            id = $("#txt_relation_code_ins").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FamilyRelationService.asmx/Insert",
                data: "{'id':'" + id + "', 'name':'" + name + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var result = response.d;
                    if (result > 0) {
                        CloseInsertDialog();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error...');
                    }
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

        function CloseInsertDialog() {
            $("#insertForm").hide();
        }

    </script>
```

---

**My web service :**

```
[WebMethod]
        public int Insert(int id, string name)
        {
            int result = -1;
            try
            {
                using (HRCTX ctx = new HRCTX())
                {
                    using (FamilyRelationRepository familyRelationRepo = new FamilyRelationRepository(ctx))
                    {
                        FAMILYRELATION family = new FAMILYRELATION
                        {
                            RELATION_CODE = id,
                            RELATION_NAME = name,
                            State = StateInterface.State.Added

                        };
                        familyRelationRepo.InsertOrUpdate(family);
                        result = ctx.Save();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: which control you want to reload

Comment: @Webruster :`ListView:lv_familyrelation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inserting using  Webmethod you need to retrieve that newly inserted row from db and you need to build the string like the following way

**aspx.cs**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetNewlyInsertedRecord()
    {
        return NewlyInsertt();
    }



public static string NewlyInsertt()
{
    dt = GetNewRecord();
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        sb.Append(


           @"<div class='row'> 
                    < div class='col-lg-4 code'>" +
               r["Code"] +
                @"</div> 
                    <div class='col-lg-4 name'>" +
                r["Name"] +
                @"</div> 
                    <div class='col-lg-4'>
                    <a onclick = 'Edit(this);' class='btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr' id='lbtn_edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> "


            );
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now in **CloseInsertDialog** Method in Aspx append like this:

```
 $("#toappend").append(response.d);
```